# MMA with a knee issue?

Tags: mixed-martial-arts, injury, safety

I'm  a 17 year old male, reasonably fit, recently got into weight training. Last year I had this knee issue called Osgood Schlatter disease. I don't have any cracks or tears, but my knee isn't quite 100% it's a little crackly and weak (especially right knee). I've met a sports physio, and he says I can start MMA. Just wanted your opinion on this, what are things I can do to prevent injury or degradation of the knee, help with rehabbing, etc.

PS. My knee has gotten better with strengthening the knee and the area around it. Physio has also given me stretches to build strength in hips, quads, hamstrings, and calf's.

Comment: Is this a request for medical advice? Check [help].

Comment: I've removed your secondary questions to focus on the original primary question. You can ask the secondary questions as new questions. Also, please take the [tour](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/tour).

Comment: Regarding close votes, I think this question is on-topic because it falls under "Injury prevention within the context of martial arts training", which is [on-topic](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple items of really good news in your description -

1. Osgood-Schlatter is pretty much an adolescent thing, that happens during growth spurts or high stress in the knee area (athletes). It basically causes inflammation where the patellar tendon inserts onto the tibia.
2. It's generally not permanent, and can be fixed with rest, over the counter meds and strengthening and stretching
3. You're already working with a physio (awesome!) and they have given you clearance.

So at this time, I would go back to MMA. However, I would also recommend that you discuss your condition, what your physio has said (A letter stating it's ok to return to MMA activity might help), and the steps you are taking to keep it under control with your instructor/coach. If they let you back into class, then I would continue to take precautions and be aware that it may flare up again.

The other good bit of news is that it generally goes away once growing is done or slows down. Just be aware, and step back and get rest if it flares up again. Also keep working the strengthening and stretching that your physio gave you. That will help the OS as well as the MMA.

Comment: Thank you very much, do you think I should wear any knee protection pads? Something like this - https://www.decathlon.in/p/8334535_mid-500-knee-brace-adult-black.html ? Also, I'm new to MMA, I have some Taekwondo experience, but that's about it.